# Boost thread.hpp include error

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am able to include boost libraries in a simple sample project without any problem and it works fine. But as soon as I include `#include <boost/thread.hpp>` in one of my other project which is already using some other libraries, I am getting the following compilation errors:

```
1>ClCompile:    
1>  ThreadManager.cpp    
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_63\boost/container/container_fwd.hpp(302): warning C4003: not enough actual parameters for macro 'dummy'     
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_63\boost/container/container_fwd.hpp(302): error C2976: 'atl::Dummy' : too few template arguments    
1>C:\program files\adaptive vision\adaptive vision studio 4.3 professional\sdk\include\ATL/Dummy.h(17) : see declaration of 'atl::Dummy'    
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_63\boost/container/container_fwd.hpp(302): error C3484: syntax error: expected '->' before the return type    
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_63\boost/container/container_fwd.hpp(302): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'Get'    
1>C:\Boost\include\boost-1_63\boost/container/container_fwd.hpp(302): error C2334: unexpected token(s) preceding '{'; skipping apparent function body    
1>    
1>Build FAILED.
```

**PS:** If I include `#include <boost/chrono.hpp>` instead of `#include <boost/thread.hpp>` then there is no error.

**PSS:** I am using Windows, Visual Studio 2010 (that's why Boost)

**Sample Code:**

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

#include <stdlib.h>

//Header for boost multithreading
//#include <boost/chrono.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

namespace avs //Adaptive Vision
{
    class MyProgram : public UserFilter
    {
        int Invoke()
        {
            //CODE
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to use `<boost/thread.hpp>` instead of `<thread>` from the C++ Standard Library?

Comment: How is it picking up the _"adaptive vision"_ includes in the middle of including boost?  Looks like 3rd party library naming issues.  If you have any `using namespace xxx` in your code try removing it/them.

Comment: @Xirema: I am using VS2010 in which its quite difficult to implement multithreading that's why I am using Boost libraries for multithreading.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Yes, adaptive vision is a third party library and the file `ThreadManager.cpp` already has a namespace `namespace avs {  ----CODE---- }`. I can add extra files but I must include them into `ThreadManager.cpp` file and it throws these errors. BTW there is no `using namespace` in the code.

Comment: Have you tried changing order of includes? It looks like name collision, the preprocessor substitutes `dummy` for `atl::dummy`. If you include boost header first, and the `dummy`-macro header second, the problem should not occur anymore?

Comment: @pmatyszok: Solved the problem for now...but is there any proper solution??

Comment: The proper solution is to avoid name collision by software producers, there are means for that, but as a user you cannot do much more. Try contacting support.